# How to add License header in maven project using java code

Tags: java, maven, plugins, license-maven-plugin

The task would add a license header if the code doesn't have one or replace it otherwise and would remove if needed.

If using command prompt-say user press -r and then enter key, then the license header is removed from all the files and if user presses -a then license is added to all the files and replaces the previous one. I tried license maven plugin but it was not removing the headers and on adding header it automatically adds one after the other everytime. Requirement is now to develop a java code for such thing now.

Is there any way you could help.
Thanks

Comment: Time to develop your own Maven plugin I guess.

Comment: I really wouldn't want Maven interfering with the source code.  Look for an IDE plugin to do it.  For example: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/copyright-wizard (not a recommendation ... just a lead.)

Comment: @Tunaki : lol yes this is what I was asked to do.. Any better solution??

Comment: @StephenC yeah wanted to do such thing but isn't working

Comment: What do you mean by better?

Comment: Any help that you can provide?

Comment: license-maven-plugin.
I used this http://code.mycila.com/license-maven-plugin/ but is not working well